# Error [FirebaseError]: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");

// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "____",
    authDomain: "____",
    projectId: "____"
  });
  
var db = firebase.firestore();

var datasetSymptom=[{
    "Disease" : [ "edema pulmonary" ],
    "Symptom" : "Heberden's node"
  }, {
    "Disease" : [ "cholecystitis" ],
    "Symptom" : "Murphy's sign"
  }, {
    "Disease" : [ "hemiparesis", "hypertension pulmonary", "transient ischemic attack" ],
    "Symptom" : "Stahli's line"
  }
  ]

datasetSymptom.forEach(function(obj) {
    db.collection("datasetSymptom").doc(obj.Symptom).set({
        Disease: obj.Disease
    })
});
```

I already ran the same algo on another collection with same `Disease` name as doc and array of symptoms as field. It worked fine.
Error:

```
D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:25868
            throw replaceFunctionName(e, 'doc()', 'CollectionReference.doc()');
            ^

Error [FirebaseError]: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but datasetSymptom/feels hot/feverish has 3.
    at new FirestoreError (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:209:28)
    at validateDocumentPath (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:19706:15)
    at doc (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:22462:9)
    at CollectionReference$1.doc (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:25864:64)
    at D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\index2x2.js:1233:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\index2x2.js:1231:16)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'invalid-argument'←[39m,
  toString: ←[36m[Function (anonymous)]←[39m
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Solved by searching for symptom containing '/' as that is invalid i replaced it with '-' it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved by searching for symptom containing '/' as that is invalid i replaced it with '-' it solved my problem –